# DASL Add Column PR_ENTRYID

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get a list of EntryIDs in the Outlook table.

I have tried below code. It shows SYSTEM.BYTE[]. Any help is much appreciated as I am new to DASL queries.

```
Dim oT As Outlook.Table = eFolder.GetTable(strFilter)
oT.Sort("[SentOn]", True)
oT.Columns.RemoveAll()

    With oT.Columns
        .Add("SenderName")
        .Add("urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription")
        .Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFF0102")
    End With

Dim VarArray As Array
VarArray = oT.GetArray(oT.GetRowCount)

For ix As Integer = 0 To RowCount - 1
   MsgBox(VarArray(ix, 7).ToString) '''''''''THIS LINE IS THE CHALLENGE'''''''''
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

`Entryid` is a binary `(PT_BINARY`) property in MAPI. You can use `MAPIFolder.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString` to convert an array to a hex string.